# Power Calculation based on data transmission with alteration in Power Output [dbm]

Tags: gsm

I was choosing the gsm module for my application. I want to register with 4G Network and want to transmit the data continously for 3 consecutive days.

I did some calculation along with power output (dbm) of the module. I noticed that in every datasheet power consumption is measured with highest power output of nearly 23dbm, but there is lack of current consumption with lowest power output [dBm], so tried to do some calculation according to the power output.

my flow of calculation is as below.

i searched for the dbm terminology and converted it to the milliwatt unit, so accordingly.
1 dbm = 1.2589254118 mW
23 dbm = 199.5262314969 mW
then i converted mW to the milliampere with standard operating current of 3.3V with this link (Watts/Volts/Amps/Ohms Calculator).

1.2589254118 mW = 0.38149255 mA
2) 199.5262314969 mW = 60.46249439mA
so according to equation, if i am transmitting the data via 1dbm it should take atleast 0.38149255 mA, and 60.46249439mA when transmitting the data via 23dbm.

does my calculation is right?

is not how should i calculate the current when considering the dbm as my prime factor to reduce the power conusmption.

I did it with esp32 wifi. I transmitted data via mqtt protocol, I tried two different configuration with lowest supportable dbm and highest supportable dbm which was causing a difference of only 10-15mA per hour which is not matching according to above mentioned calculations, letme know what i am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

Power equals current times voltage for DC only.  You need to use RMS values, which vary depending on the waveform type.